# How to decode base64 text to binary file?

Tags: javascript, binary, base64, blob

I am converting binary file's buffer to base64 text before storing to mongodb. I am using multer to get image alongside with with other field. I am sending those data in `FormData` and the back end is

```
app.post('/image', multer().single('image'), (req, res) => {
    const image = Buffer.from(req.file.buffer).toString('base64')
    database.collection('images').insertOne({image})
}
```

Now, how do I decode this `base64` text to binary image?

I tried this in the front end after getting the json from the back end

```
URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([window.atob(data.image)]))
```

But I think the binary file is corrupted.

Comment: Why are you converting the image in the first place? MongoDb is using BSON and therefore capable of storing raw binary data which would be much more efficient.

Comment: @Egge, Okay, then, how do I convert it back if I store it as raw? What I am saying is if I get it as binary format on the front end, how do I use it as image source?

Comment: In that case no conversion would be required. Send the image as Buffer, and receive it as ArrayBuffer using fetch.

Comment: @Egge, Do I need to do any extra step when I sending the image from back end to the front end?

Comment: Flow looks like this: Save file in mongo db as Buffer -> Retrieve file as Buffer -> Send response containing buffer to frontend -> receive reponse on frontend and "convert" to ArrayBuffer -> do whatever you want with the binary data

Comment: @Egge, I have found a problem. I am saving it as binary in the mongodb. I am sending back it as binary. But, when I console.log it I am getting base64 data instead of buffer.

Comment: Are you using reponse.arrayBuffer() to read the response on your client side?

Comment: @Egge, it is showing ArrayBuffer { byteLength: 10000 } something like this. Now what do I do with it? I am still confused

Comment: You can turn it into a blob and do whatever you like with it. for example:
const imageUrl = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(<your ArrayBuffer>, {type:'image/png'}));

Comment: Is there a design problem setting an image element's `src` attribute to an endpoint of the server that processes the  GET request by getting the binary data from  the data base before sending it back with a content type header set to the image's MIME type?